# Certificate error for stackoverflow.help

Tags: bug, status-completed, ssl, stack-overflow-for-teams

When visiting the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), a banner is displayed:

[image]

The "Click here »" link points to `https://stackoverflow.help/`, which when visited redirects to `https://www.stackoverflow.help/` and presents a certificate error:

> This server could not prove that it is www.stackoverflow.help; its security certificate is from *.freshdesk.com. This may be caused by a misconfiguration or an attacker intercepting your connection.

Comment: yeah.. thats the help center for StackOverflow for Teams /Channels. And it is handled by freshdesk.com

Comment: I understand that, my point is that it shouldn't give a certificate error.

Comment: My intention was to clarify to the community as not everyone will have a teams account and wont see the banner. Same reason I added the tag.

Comment: I also don't have a teams account as far as I know. Thanks for the edit!

Comment: Then that could be another issue :D

Comment: Seems like they fixed the issue .

Comment: Yap problem solved but answer is not appear .

Comment: I don't have Teams, but I see banner too. I don't need/like/going to use it.. Can it just go away please?

Comment: @Sinatr or if it's going to stay, then it needs a WTF is Teams page for the majority of users who don't follow meta.